# Why do the changes made in one variable result in the changes in related variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have run a code as follows:
data_model = data2

data_model.drop("Sale",axis = 1,inplace = True)
This results in the removal of sale column from the data_model dataframe as well as the data2 dataframe. why? does it act like a pointer to data2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: `data_model = data2` simply says "the name `data_model` now refers to the object referenced by `data2`. Note, in the future, please always tag any python related questions with the generic [python] tag

Comment: I did. Are you suggesting that I should put up a generic [python] tag only for such questions?

Comment: No, you did not. You can see in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58531273/revisions) that I added the generic tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `data_model = data2` is just a pointer and does not create a copy, therefore editing one is also editing the other... you have to use this:

```
data_model = data2.copy()
```

And read the [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)